# Installing nagios plugins

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, nagios

I have worked my way through installing Ubuntu and getting nagios up and running and now monitoring about 60 windows clients with NSCleint. This is working great but now I want to add UPS monitoring to the setup. I have found this plugin [check_apcupsd](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/UPS/APC/check_apcupsd/details)
that will work with apcupsd software that's already installed.

Now Im not sure how to go about installing and configuring this plugin (or any plugin for that matter) and would like some guidance.

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
Nagios 3

Comment: from repositories or compiled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a new plugin, you need to do the following:

1. Drop your new plugin in the plugins folder `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/`.
2. Define the appropriate check_command.
3. Define the USP service and uses the defined check_command with the suitable arguments.
4. Reload/restart your nagios server.