# Beginner trying to install nagios plugin.

Tags: monitoring, nagios, ups

I have setup Nagios following the quickstart guide and have managed to get a few servers monitored. good. Now, 
Nagios plugins are new to me and as a result I have no idea what I need to do to get this plug in to work.

My goal is to get UPS status from a couple of servers. 
The plug in is [check_apcupsd](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/UPS/APC/check_apcupsd/details)

Can somebody please explain step by step how I go about getting this to run?

There are no instructions provided in the link.

Answer (score 3):

You are to download that plugin, remove txt extension and put it to the

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/
```

folder. Then give permissions to user nagiosadmin to run this plugin and restart nagios by using

```
/etc/init.d/nagios restart
```

(look [Installing nagios plugins](https://serverfault.com/questions/351451/installing-nagios-plugins)). The second step specified in the accepted answer is to define the check_command. You can do it as follows: 
launch `./check_apcupsd` in terminal and see its usage. Then move to `/etc/nagios-plugins/config` and create file apcupsd.cfg with contents like this

```
    # check_apcupsd command definition
define command{
    command_name    check_apcupsd_battery
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apcupsd bcharge
    }
etc.
```

For examples you can consult other config files stored in the same directory.